# Integral of the functional sequence

Tags: real-analysis

We have a functional sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{n\ln(1 + x)}{nx + 1}$, then $f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ and $x \ge 0, n = 1, 2, ...$. The answers of this task say that the integral $(*) \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ exists and is equal to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$.

But I don't understand why.

As I understand $f(x)=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$. If we consider this sequence on the $(0; 1]$ we can understand that there is no uniform convergence on this interval. Indeed, $\rho_n = |f_n(x)-f(x)|=|\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(nx+1)}|$ and if we take $x_n=1/n$, we get $\rho_n = |\frac{n\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})}{2}| \not\to 0,\, n \to \infty$. But as I know for the existence of the integral $(*) $ uniform convergence is necessary. Please, help me to comprehend, where is a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you stated is correct, except for the last statement: uniform convergence is sufficient for the existence of the integral $(*)$, but it is not necessary.

Another example is $f_n(x) = nx e^{-nx}$ on $[0, 1]$. It's easy to see that these functions are uniformly bounded and converge to zero uniformly on each interval $[a, 1]$, where $a > 0$, hence $\int \limits_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \to 0$. But $f(x)$ doesn't converge to zero uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Oh, really. Thank you very much!

Comment: But can we say, that if the itegral (*) exists it is surely equal to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1f_n(x)dx$ ?

Comment: @DF Depends on the assumptions. If $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n & \text{if } 0 < x < \frac{1}{n} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise but $\int \limits_0^1 f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = 1$ for every $n$. A small modification makes $f_n$ continuous while still being a counterexample. But perhaps we can put more restrictions to make the claim true.

Comment: I've understood, thank you. But in my initial question, now I can prove that the integral (*) exists, but how can I prove that this itegral is equal to that limit? $\int \frac{nln(1+x)}{nx + 1}dx$ doesn't seem to be expressed in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: @DF The functions $f_n(x)$ are continuous and $f(x)$ is continuous except at $x=0$, hence they are Riemann integrable. For each $x \in [0, 1]$ we have $0 \leqslant f_n(x) \leqslant 1$. Also if $a > 0$, then $f_n(x) \rightrightarrows f(x)$ on $[a, 1]$. Show that in general these three conditions imply that $\int \limits_0^1 f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \to \int \limits_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. The intuition is, for small $a > 0$ both integrals over $[0, a]$ are small and $\int \limits_a^1 |f_n(x)-f(x)| \, \mathrm{d} x$ becomes small due to uniform convergence.

Comment: Once again many thanks :)